# Rails systeml() Shell command Call fails in Server but works well in Rails console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, shell, nginx

I deployed my Rails project using capistrano, nginx, ec2.

```
def hwp_convert(filepath)
  Rails.logger.info "hwp_convert"
  Rails.logger.info system("pwd")
  Rails.logger.info system("ls")
  Rails.logger.info system "hwp5odt",filepath
  Rails.logger.info "process done"
  result = filepath.split(/\//).last
  a = result.split(/\./).first
  result = "#{Rails.root}/#{a}.odt"
  Rails.logger.info result
  return result
end
```

I tried 
    system hwp5odt,filepath

[here is a screenshot of rails console.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iZLao.png)

hwp5odt is a python module converts hwp file to odt file.
It works well returns true in rails console (bundle exec rails c production)but in web server it returns nil

Is there any idea? Whats difference between rails c production and web condition?

Comment: Looks like a `$PATH` issue. Run `where hwp5odt` in prod, and update your script _specifying the full path to `hwp5odt` script_.

Comment: I see `sudo` in the screenshot. That seems worrisome, and also could be the cause of your issues (it may be resetting `$PATH`).

Comment: Thanks a lot!!!! I It was a path problem. I found path using which hwp5odt command. you guys saved my day. Thank you